# Cucumber extent report - how to add screenshot of failed case to the extent report

Tags: java, selenium, cucumber, extentreports

I found no solutions for the screenshot of failed case to the extent report in Cucumber (Java). I have look elsewhere in Stack Overflow. Can anyone kindly help me troubleshoot? File `pom.xml` posting my dependencies for Cucumber reports

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.relevantcodes</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>2.41.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
 <groupId>com.vimalselvam</groupId>
 <artifactId>cucumber-extentsreport</artifactId>
 <version>3.0.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports</artifactId>
    <version>3.1.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.aventstack</groupId>
    <artifactId>extentreports-cucumber4-adapter</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.6</version>
</dependency>
```

/*runner class */ plugin and run method

```
     plugin = {"com.cucumber.listener.ExtentCucumberFormatter:target/cucumber-reports/report.html"}

public class testRunner{
    @AfterClass
     public static void writeExtentReport() {
         Reporter.loadXMLConfig(new File("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipseworkspace\\test\\extent-config.xml"));    
}
```

/* step class */

```
  @After
        public void execute_after_every_scenario(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException, IOException
        {
            testbase.teardown(scenario);
        }
```

/* test base class */
what is working are the screenshots saved in output folder
**what is missing are the screenshots in extent report**

```
public static void teardown(Scenario scenario) throws InterruptedException, IOException
    {
        Thread.sleep(2000);
        if (scenario.isFailed()) {
               try {
                   String screenshotName = scenario.getName().replaceAll(" ", "_"); 
                   byte[] screenshot = ((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
                File screenshot_with_scenario_name = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE); 
              //  FileUtils.copyFile(screenshot_with_scenario_name, new File("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\testscreenshots\\" + screenshotName + ".png"));
              
                System.out.println("testing pring the screenshot" + screenshotName);              

              File destinationPath = new File("C:\\Users\\User\\eclipse-workspace\\test\\testscreenshots\\" + screenshotName + ".png");
                  
     //Copy taken screenshot from source location to destination location
                Files.copy(screenshot_with_scenario_name.toPath(), destinationPath.toPath()); 

            Reporter.addScreenCaptureFromPath(destinationPath.toString());
                Reporter.addScenarioLog(screenshotName);
                
                scenario.embed(screenshot, "image/png");
       
               } catch (IOException somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots) {
                System.err.println(somePlatformsDontSupportScreenshots.getMessage());
           }  
              }
```

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1kYn44-5Fy4 This link will help you create method for failure

Comment: thanks for your comment! i assumed that is code with testNG, i am asking how can we add screenshots to extent report.

Answer (score 0):

1. scenario.embed adds screenshot to cucumber default reporting.
2. This link would solve your issue for attaching screenshot to extent report.

https://www.toolsqa.com/selenium-cucumber-framework/cucumber-extent-report/

Comment: hi, i have edited my post above by adding Files.copy(screenshot_with_scenario_name.toPath(), destinationPath.toPath()); the result has no changes, still no screenshots from extent report. any advise?

Comment: Remove FileUtils.Copyfile and see if that helps.

Answer (score -1):

Try this below code logic

```
    @After(order=1)
    public void tearDown(Scenario scenario)
    {
        if(scenario.isFailed())
        {
            //take screenshot
            String screenshotName =scenario.getName().replaceAll("", "_");
            byte[] sourcepath =((TakesScreenshot)driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.BYTES);
            scenario.attach(sourcepath, "image/png", screenshotName);
        }       
    }
```